# pyTelegramBotAPI - как получить переменную из другого файла

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть два скрипта, один `bot.py`, второй `code_ext.py`, второй скрипт имеет в себе Handler команды `/code` и обработку введеной команды, но мне нужно как-то использовать переменную из главного скрипта, я пытался импортировать родительский скрипт в code_ext.py, но когда bot.py импортирует code_ext.py и запускает функцию, code_ext.py запускает bot.py и например при инициализации родительского скрипта он может написать в консоль два раза сообщение, как мне в code_ext.py использовать переменные из скрипта bot.py, желательно без импорта, или как пофиксить?

Comment: например: перенесите переменные в третий файл, и подключайте его из двух названных.

Comment: А есть еще аналоги, например не в файл переносить, а использовать как-то еще?

Comment: в базу данных можно поместить (концептуально тот же самый «отдельный файл»).